# How to Store JSON array data of android app remotely?

Tags: android, json, online-storage

I have created an android app where the data is being managed in JSON Array. App is working fine but i would like to share data of application in different mobiles, is there a possibility to save data remotely in internet and sync that json to my other devices. I am assuming some way like from my application if i click a button the JSON data will be stored in Google drive, and if i click sync data button from another mobile the data from the google drive location should download to my device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can use firebase and convert json to gson string using serialize deserialize and convery to string and send and fetch from other side convery gson to json. any query ?
help:-https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Comment: Thanks @Vishal for quick help

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: your welcome @raghudatta

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic situation for firebase! It allows you to store remotely data in a real-time remote database, you can also manage users, analytics, have some storage, geofence (with geofire) and many more. 
Checkout this you won't regret it [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)

Comment: Thanks @BNAndroid for quick help